# How can you merge two variables into one?

Tags: statistics

Suppose there are two variables which are both likely to have an effect on another single variable. How could you combine those two into one variable, such that you only have one input variable in the function.
I believe the best way is to somehow convert the data from one of the variables to the "scale" of the other variable, and then have the sum of the two variables as the new variable. However, I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: If $f(x,y)\in K[x,y]$ is, say, a polynomial in $x$ and $y$, then just consider it as a function of $y$ only, i.e., $g(y)=f(x)(y)\in K[x][y]$.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a graph for example variables x,y then draw graph plotting (x,y) then make equation of straight line / circle / ellipse / parabola….